# Android and SQLite: When to use semicolons to end statements?

Tags: android, sqlite

If you are using the `rawQuery()` or `execSQL()` methods of SQLite on Android, when should you use a semicolon to end your statement?

On [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), for instance, the author uses the semicolon on the create table statement (via execSQL), but not on select statement (via rawQuery). For instance:

Create Table Statement:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";
database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

Select Statement:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().
  rawQuery("select * from todo where _id = ?", new String[] { id });
```

Is it the case that statements using the `execSQL()` method need a semicolon at the end, but statements using the `rawQuery()` method don't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQLite statements are terminated by a semicolon (`;`). If one is specified, it means it's the end of a command, and that more commands can follow that semicolon. If no semicolon is specified, the entire string is taken to be the command.

In this case, the semicolon in the `CREATE` statement does not matter, as nothing follows it.

Comment: Gotcha. So as long as I am sending one single command the semicolon is entirely optional?

Comment: I think this is it. If you use SQL from a command-line, you have to put in the semicolon no matter what. A lot of SQL APIs seem to pop the semicolon at the end if one isn't there.

Comment: @JoePlante Yeah, I think that's right. It was part of the ANSI-92 SQL standard but I don't think it was mandated outside of the command line.

Comment: Just to note, multiple commands are not supported with `execSQL()`:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

I've never used semicolon in both and it works