# Android SQLiteDatabase inser error

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, sql-insert

I'm trying to store in a SQLiteDatabase some information. 
When I call the method insert, it returns -1. So an error occurred, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here's the code:

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Find";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_BIRTHDAY + "TEXT" + KEY_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT"
            + KEY_CITY + "TEXT" + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 */
public void addUser(String name, String last_name, String email, String birthday, String description,
                    String city, String uid, String created_at) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, last_name); // Last Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_BIRTHDAY, birthday); // Birthday
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description); // Description
    values.put(KEY_CITY, city); // City
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Unique ID
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created at

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("last_name", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("birthday", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("description", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("city", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(8));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database. Delete all tables and create them again
 */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: May fail because one value is NULL?

Comment: @AndreaR., a few things. Since you can comment I suggest you delete your answer & communicate with us through the comments. Second, you did not specify `NOT NULL` in your table, so a `null` value should be okay.

Comment: @AndreaR., next, try deleting the app & re-deploying it, if the table was created incorrectly, this will make the app create it again.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named description (code 1). This is the error, but the column exist. Solution?

Comment: do you did what we have told you to do ? I mean, change the sql to the new CREATE TABLE we provide, and do what @DanielK said, to delete de app from your device or emulator and reinstall?

Comment: it probably will fix the problem.

Comment: @AndreaR., yup you made a table that is missing a few of columns because of a bad SQL statement. To get rid of the table, delete the app, then redeploy it your device and as Lucas said, make sure you actually change your create statement.

Comment: Done right now, and it's working! Thanks u both!

Comment: Great teamwork @LucasPaolillo!

Comment: Yes!! that kind of discussion is always great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your create SQL is wrong, you have missed ',' and spaces, use the below.

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ");";
```

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because it's missing a semicolon at the end? Most SQL statements require a semicolon to end them.

Comment: You right, MOST, just when you have more then one sql statement. if not, you can forget semicolon. I know its a good pratice to set it, however, its not mandatory when you have a single statement. So, its a good pratice, i edit my answer.

Comment: From what I understand, that only applies to TSQL, which admittedly I don't use, do you have any references I could read?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202600/android-and-sqlite-when-to-use-semicolons-to-end-statements
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/complete.html

Comment: Thank you so much for that reference. I had this conversation with another user recently & we both came up empty. Again, thank you very much for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_BIRTHDAY + "TEXT" + KEY_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT"
            + KEY_CITY + "TEXT" + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Should be:

```
String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ");";
```

You were missing several commas, spaces & a semicolon to end your SQL statement (Not necessary but good practice). Your table must not have been created at all or not all fields were created if it was created.